# Python OpenPyXL Errors When Saving File

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, openpyxl

I just started learning Python in October and I am not sure how to proceed.  I have a script which ran just fine, until I added some code for openpyxl to open an Excel file, delete the last (unneeded) column, and then save the file.  Everything works fine, until the script gets to the "wb.save(*filename*)"; I get the errors listed below.

I have tried the script on 2 Windows 10 PCs, both with Anaconda3 (2019-07), Python 3.7.6.  I have openpyxl 3.0.0 on one of the PCs, and 3.0.2 on the other.  The PC with 3.0.2 was a fresh install of Anaconda, just to see if it the problem was with the existing installation on the other PC.  I have also tried to uninstall and reinstall openpyxl, and still get the errors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\npl1sxr\Documents\Python\NewAccounts\qptAccounts.py", line 130, in <module>
    makeExcelFiles(df, wedt, westdt)

  File "C:\Users\npl1sxr\Documents\Python\NewAccounts\qptAccounts.py", line 65, in makeExcelFiles
    wb.save('C:\\Users\\NPL1SXR\\Documents\\Python\\NewAccounts\\Export\\AccountsNew.xlsx')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 408, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 75, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 354, in write
    self.write_top()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 98, in write_top
    self.write_properties()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 60, in write_properties
    self.xf.send(props.to_tree())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 294, in get_stream
    xf.write(el)

  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 1652, in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter.write

TypeError: got invalid input value of type <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>, expected string or Element
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? See: [mcve].

Comment: @AMC: I apologize.  Most of the code contains proprietary company information.  However, the script worked just fine until I added the following lines:

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\NPL1SXR\\Documents\\Python\\NewAccounts\\Export\\AccountsNew.xlsx')

ws = wb.active


ws.delete_cols(ws.max_column)

wb.save('C:\\Users\\NPL1SXR\\Documents\\Python\\NewAccounts\\Export\\AccountsNew.xlsx')

Comment: pip install -U openpyxl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my problem was with openpyxl version 3.0.0 or newer.  Removing openpyxl 3.0.2 caused 30+ other packages to be removed.  After reinstalling the other packages one by one, I was able to install openpyxl 2.6.2.  No more errors!

```
>>> conda install openpyxl==2.6.2
```

Edited approximately 3 hours after my original "Answer" post, when I came across this page: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1373.  The errors are exactly the same as my initial post.  The issue was with openpyxl 3.0.2 specifically.  As of 1/21/2020, openpyxl 3.0.3 is not available through conda, so I had to install is with pip.

```
>>> pip install --upgrade openpyxl
```

Tested it with my original script and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Visit this link [answer](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Need-help-in-understanding- 
                 this-particular-Traceback-TypeError)
This Problem come due to openpyxl=3.0.2

Switch back to openpyxl=3.0.1

>>> conda remove openpyxl
>>> conda install openpyxl==3.0.1
```

or

```
>>> pip uninstall openpyxl
>>> pip install openpyxl==3.0.1
```